# Kotlin Load WebView is not working every time

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I currently have a WebView which normally should display a trackmap. On the simulator it works everytime, but on a physical device it sometimes works and sometime its just display the black background. I have read a lot of answers now but nothing really worked for my problem.

This is my MapActivity.kt where the logic of my map is inside.

```
@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
class MapActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "MapActivity"

    val args: MapActivityArgs by navArgs()
    var mMap: String? = null

    private lateinit var pb: ProgressBar

    //Progress bar when initialize the SVG file.
    fun initProgressDialog() {
        Log.d(TAG,"LOADED!")
        pb = ProgressBar(this)
        pb.isIndeterminate = true
    }

    override public fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+args.map)
        this.mMap = args.map
        // TODO: 30.09.2021 Do something with me 
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+SimplePossession.State.valueOf(args.possessionState))
        setupButtonActions()
        setupWebLayout()
    }

    /** Setup the Action Buttons
     * btn_plus = ZoomIn for map
     * btn_minus = ZoomOut for map
     * btn_back = btn to go back to possession
     * btn_confirm = btn to confirm map section
     */
    fun setupButtonActions() {
        initProgressDialog()

        btn_plus.setOnClickListener{
            Log.e("Btn", "BtnZoomIN")
            wv_map.zoomIn() }
        btn_minus.setOnClickListener {
            Log.e("Btn","BtnZoomOUT")
            wv_map.zoomOut() }
        btn_back.setOnClickListener{
            Log.e("Btn","Btn back")
            onBackPressed();
        }
        btn_confirm.setOnClickListener {
            /** If possessionDetailsFragment variable set on true, means possession has
             * state: start approved or started
             * click on confirm btn set checkbox on true and return on PossessionDetails View
             */
            PossessionAreaTableEntryViewHolder.setCheckedCB(true);
            onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        callVM()
    }

    fun callVM() {
        try {
            var apiResponse : String? = ""
            try{
                apiResponse = mMap
            } catch(e: Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            if (apiResponse != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "callVM: TEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEST")
                wv_map.loadData(Base64.encodeToString(apiResponse.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Base64.DEFAULT),
                        "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64")
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("FAIL", "Initializing failed")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("AddJavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    fun setupWebLayout() {

        wv_map.clearView()
        wv_map.setInitialScale(150)
        wv_map.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
        wv_map.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
        wv_map.settings.displayZoomControls = false
        wv_map.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        wv_map.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        wv_map.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy()
    }

}
```

The map will be loaded via API Response and is in html format. I doublechecked if my MapActivity really receive the map in html format - it does. The background is strangely enough loaded correclty everytime (its just a black background and on top there normally is the track, but the track doesn't load everytime)...

My idea was a cache-problem, so i tried to clear the cache before reading the map again. Does not fix my problem.
Then clearing the whole map variable before reloading the map. Does not fix my problem.

I dont have another idea to fix this so I hope someone here does have an idea:)

EDIT: Permission in AndroidManifest are given:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.siemens.poms">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, that my Webview won't be detached from window, when I go back to my menu screen... So ..The solution is detach the Webview from my window and reload it...

i used wv_map.destroy() for that...

Maybe someone will have a similiar error.